# Can someone explain what are Slivers and Delegates in flutter and why to use them?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

["Link to code"](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_shopper/lib/screens/catalog.dart)

I was following the Flutter State Management tutorial and came across this.

Please explain what are `Slivers`, `Delegates`. Especially this part that I have attached.

```
class MyCatalog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          _MyAppBar(),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 12)),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => _MyListItem(index)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say it briefly: Slivers special animation area. [Slivers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers)
You have a lot of option slivers widget also normal widgets (SliverGrid => GridView). Sliver scroll affects the biggest difference in normal listview.

Slivers ok, so what is ChildDelegate?

Delegate: Slivers draw type. Maybe sometimes set array builder function need. SliverListDelegate Delagete needs children array also SliverListBuilderDelagate return builder function and children count. [Child Delegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverChildBuilderDelegate-class.html)